# Best way to sort an array of date string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

what would be the best way to sort an array of date strings as such :

```
var array = ["Tue 7/28", "Sat 8/1", "Sun 8/2", "Mon 7/27", "Thu 7/30", "Fri 7/31", "Wed 7/29"];
```

into this:

```
var array = ["Mon 7/27", "Tue 7/28", "Wed 7/29", "Thu 7/30", "Fri 7/31", "Sat 8/1", "Sun 8/2"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the dates comparable somehow, so you can use a function to convert them into something comparable. You can skip the weekday and get the month and day and turn that into a number:

```
function decodeDate(s) {
  parts = s.substr(4).split('/');
  return parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 40 + parseInt(parts[1], 10);
}
```

Using that you can sort the array:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){ return decodeDate(a) - decodeDate(b); });
```

Demo:

```js
function decodeDate(s) {
  parts = s.substr(4).split('/');
  return parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 40 + parseInt(parts[1], 10);
}

var array = ["Tue 7/28", "Sat 8/1", "Sun 8/2", "Mon 7/27", "Thu 7/30", "Fri 7/31", "Wed 7/29"];

array.sort(function(a, b){ return decodeDate(a) - decodeDate(b); });

document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: @JohnDoe: I'm not an alot. ;) https://www.google.se/search?q=alot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIwI7StsSaxwIVSQ0sCh0thAR1&biw=1187&bih=922